# Nodemon Crash after app has been running for several hours

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have a web application running as a service on an Ubuntu EC2 Instance. As of the past 24 hours, the application has been crashing randomly 2-4 hours after running with the message attached in the image below. The error is:

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

I have run into this error before but usually, it is a syntax error and it will not allow me to actually start the application. In this case, the app functions normally for several hours before crashing. I have no idea where to even start as there's nothing above it that looks like it could be causing the crash. The only thing is it looks like the website receives 3 Get / Requests before the server can respond then it crashes. Most of the posts I've found online about this also block the application from running and don't mention the fact that the app runs normally then crashes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[Error Log from Journalctl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go1SF.png)

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @NiklasE. I can't reproduce it myself in local environments. I wish I could give you code but I don't know what part of the code could possibly be failing to give it to you. I apologize for this.

Comment: I see the issue, *but* the minimum requirements at SO are, that you'd post the code relevant to the issue in the question itself, and describe the problem in details. What you want your code to do, and what it does instead. So your question is probably not suitable for the site. It looks like a silent error. I would try to log every input (e.g. http request and timeouts) with timestamp and also log the crash with time. When a crash occurs I would compare the time to events happening right before. Also check system logs at `/var/log/`. Mind that some other program could have killed the task...

Comment: ...  Or even something else like e.g. if you start the task over ssh it will stop after a while then the ssh connection is lost or closed.

Comment: @NiklasE. Tracked it down. OOMKiller was terminating my service as RAM was too low on my instance. If you want to put something along the lines of "Check your /var/log/ stupid" I'll accept the answer cause that pointed me right to it. Appreciate it!

Comment: Otherwise ill just delete the question as it had nothing to do with Nodemon or Node.js at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a silent error. I would try to log every input (e.g. http request and timeouts) with timestamp and also log the crash with time. When a crash occurs I would compare the time to events happening right before.
Also check your `/var/log/` if the programm was terminated by the system or another programm.